# BeautifulSoup - find + iterate through a table

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am having some trouble trying to cleanly iterate through [a table of sold property listings](http://house.ksou.cn/p.php?q=West%20Footscray%2C%20VIC) using BeautifulSoup.

In this example

- Some rows in the main table are irrelevant (like "set search filters")
- The rows have unique IDs
- Have tried getting the rows using a style attribute, but this did not return results.

**What would be the best approach to get just the rows for sold properties out of that table?**

End goal is to pluck out the sold price; date of sale; # bedrooms/bathrooms/car; land area and append into a pandas dataframe.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

# Globals
headers = ({'User-Agent':
        'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'})
url = 'http://house.ksou.cn/p.php?q=West+Footscray%2C+VIC'

r=requests.get(url,headers=headers)
c=r.content
soup=BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")

r=requests.get(url,headers=headers)
c=r.content
soup=BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")

prop_table = soup.find('table', id="mainT")
#prop_table = soup.find('table', {"font-size" : "13px"})
#prop_table = soup.select('.addr') # Pluck out the listings


rows = prop_table.findAll('tr')                    

for row in rows:
    print(row.text)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you need the items across the entire pagination or just the first page?

Comment: The first 5 pages.  I have a similar script (for a different site) that does this.  Does this affect the approach?

Comment: No, not really, it's just a matter of adding a loop to it. I was just curious if I should go through the trouble. Thanks for clarifying

Comment: What’s the problem, exactly? Is part of your code accidentally duplicated here?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile - apologies, have edited it down further.  Duplicate was due to some troubleshooting steps I was attempting (now removed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This HTML is tricky to parse, because it doesn't have fixed structure. Unfortunately, I don't have pandas installed, so I only print the data to the screen:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://house.ksou.cn/p.php?q=West+Footscray&p={page}&s=1&st=&type=&count=300&region=West+Footscray&lat=0&lng=0&sta=vic&htype=&agent=0&minprice=0&maxprice=0&minbed=0&maxbed=0&minland=0&maxland=0'

data = []
for page in range(0, 2):    # <-- increase to number of pages you want to crawl
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url.format(page=page)).text, 'html.parser')
    for table in soup.select('table[id^="r"]'):
        name = table.select_one('span.addr').text
        price = table.select_one('span.addr').find_next('b').get_text(strip=True).split()[-1]
        sold = table.select_one('span.addr').find_next('b').find_next_sibling(text=True).replace('in', '').replace('(Auction)', '').strip()

        beds = table.select_one('img[alt="Bed rooms"]')
        beds = beds.find_previous_sibling(text=True).strip() if beds else '-'

        bath = table.select_one('img[alt="Bath rooms"]')
        bath = bath.find_previous_sibling(text=True).strip() if bath else '-'

        car = table.select_one('img[alt="Car spaces"]')
        car = car.find_previous_sibling(text=True).strip() if car else '-'

        land = table.select_one('b:contains("Land size:")')
        land = land.find_next_sibling(text=True).split()[0] if land else '-'

        building = table.select_one('b:contains("Building size:")')
        building = building.find_next_sibling(text=True).split()[0] if building else '-'

        data.append([name, price, sold, beds, bath, car, land, building])

# print the data
print('{:^25} {:^15} {:^15} {:^15} {:^15} {:^15} {:^15} {:^15}'.format('Name', 'Price', 'Sold', 'Beds', 'Bath', 'Car', 'Land', 'Building'))
for row in data:
    print('{:<25} {:^15} {:^15} {:^15} {:^15} {:^15} {:^15} {:^15}'.format(*row))
```

Prints:

```
          Name                 Price           Sold            Beds            Bath             Car            Land          Building    
51 Fontein Street            $770,000       07 Dec 2019          -               -               -               -               -       
50 Fontein Street            $751,000       07 Dec 2019          -               -               -               -               -       
9 Wellington Street         $1,024,999       Dec 2019            2               1               1              381              -       
239 Essex Street             $740,000       07 Dec 2019          2               1               1              358             101      
677a Barkly Street           $780,000        Dec 2019            4               1               -              380              -       
23A Busch Street             $800,000       30 Nov 2019          3               1               1              215              -       
3/2-4 Dyson Street           $858,000        Nov 2019            3               2               -              378             119      
3/101 Stanhope Street        $803,000       30 Nov 2019          2               2               2              168             113      
2/4 Rondell Avenue           $552,500       30 Nov 2019          2               -               -             1,088             -       
3/2 Dyson Street             $858,000       30 Nov 2019          3               2               2              378              -       
9 Vine Street                $805,000        Nov 2019            2               1               2              318              -       
39 Robbs Road                $957,000       23 Nov 2019          2               2               -              231             100      
29 Robbs Road               $1,165,000       Nov 2019            2               1               1              266              -       
5 Busch Street               $700,000        Nov 2019            2               1               1              202              -       
46 Indwe Street              $730,000       16 Nov 2019          3               1               1              470              -       
29/132 Rupert Street         $216,000       16 Nov 2019          1               1               1             3,640             -       
11/10 Carmichael Street      $385,000       15 Nov 2019          2               1               1             1,005             -       
2/16 Carmichael Street       $515,000       14 Nov 2019          2               1               1              112              -       
4/26 Beaumont Parade         $410,000        Nov 2019            2               1               1              798              -       
5/10 Carmichael Street       $310,000        Nov 2019            1               1               1             1,004             -
```

Comment: That's great!  And thanks for clarifying about the lack of structure.  I was not expecting the answer to involve that much logic.    Let me step through it and better understand whats happening.  Big thank you.

Comment: Works a charm.  Have it in a dataframe now, and iterating over a few different suburbs.  The find_next_sibling was new to me, thanks for everything